# Python - parsing apache config with regexp

Tags: python, regex, apache, configuration, apache2

I want to parse configuration files like apache2.conf, which looks like this:

```
<Group group1>
   param1 1

   <SomeGroup group3>
      param3 3
   </SomeGroup>
</Group>

<Group group2>
   param2 2
</Group>
```

Regexp:

```
re.findall(r'\</?[^\>]+\>([\s\S]+)\<//?[^\>]+\>', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

if I use lazy regexp, it cuts like this:

```
<Group group1>
   param1 1

   <SomeGroup group3>
      param3 3
   </SomeGroup>
```

If I use greedy regexp, it cuts all the text. So, what is the correct way to parse it? Or is there any libraries?

Comment: __Don't parse XML with regex.__ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @katrielalex: apache config files are not valid XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any python libs for parsing apache config files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237209/any-python-libs-for-parsing-apache-config-files)

Comment: Still, using regexes on this kind of data is just not a good idea. Build a parser if one does not already exist. A regex (if even possible) will become horribly convoluted quickly.

Comment: @katrielalex not a duplicate - the main question is how to write correct regexp.

Comment: You need to find `param 1-3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Augeas](http://augeas.net/news.html) has [python bindings](http://augeas.net/download.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use this lib!

Comment: Augeas is kind of weird and hard to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with regexp alone. The regexp engine has no state, so you can only parse very simple input. See here for other options: [Any python libs for parsing apache config files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237209/any-python-libs-for-parsing-apache-config-files)